# Use a mouse for non-mouse input

Tags: c++, linux, mouse, usb

So the question I have today has to do with interfacing with a USB mouse plugged into a linux machine.  However, I don't want the mouse to have any traditional effect on the X environment -- I just want to be able utilize the encoders embedded within it through raw input.  So here's my question.

How can I obtain low level but meaningful data from alternate mouse devices within c++ in linux?  Specifically, I would like to know relative position or at least encoder counts along both the x and y axes.

Comment: You don't want "any traditional effect on the X environment," but you do want the x and y axes? Don't coordinates only have meaning/availability in an X environment?

Comment: I don't know?  Do they?  If the raw data isn't in relative x-y differencing, how is it encoded?

Answer (score 4):

I've done something similar for a USB barcode reader that presents as a HID keyboard.

In recent kernels, there will be an event device for the mouse in `/dev/input/event*`.  If you open that and grab that with the EVIOCGRAB ioctl(), it won't send mouse events to any other app.  You can then read events straight off the mouse - see the evdev interface documentation in `Documentation/input/input.txt` in the linux source code distro.

When you read from the event device, you'll get a whole number of input events, in the following form:

```
struct input_event {
    struct timeval time;
    unsigned short type;
    unsigned short code;
    unsigned int value;
};
```

(`struct input_event` and the following macros are all defined in `linux/input.h`).

The events you're interested in will have `input_event.type == EV_REL` (relative movement event), the `input_event.code` member will be something like `REL_X` (indicating X-axis - see the `linux/input.h` file for the full list), and `input_event.value` will be the displacement.

There is no need to implement the HID protocol yourself, as another answer suggests.

Comment: Will this work for multiple USB mice that need to be tracked independently?

Comment: @Gerhman: Yes, each mouse will have its own `/dev/input/event*` device.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the HID (Human Interface Device) protocol

http://www.usb.org/developers/devclass_docs/HID1_11.pdf

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_interface_device